# Keep getting Error: Could not find or load main class although set the PATH and CLASSPATH variables

Tags: java

I was trying to run my first JAVA code, so after installing the JDK12 on my Windows10 machine, I checked that the JAVA is installed correctly, I also was able to compile the file but when tried to run the code using the java command I got this error: Could not find or load main class

I installed JDK12 from the oracle website
I tried to read and find some examples but in all the examples I saw that they set the CLASSPATH to the JRE folder (for some reason I don't have JRE folder under the SDK installation folder and I don't know if this is correct)

```
public class FirstJavaProgram {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("This is my first program in java");
  }//End of main
}//End of FirstJavaProgram Class
```

I was expecting to see the text of the first program on the screen and instead I got the error mentioned above

I am adding more information hopefully it will give you more clues to help me:

The code that I shared above is the full code of the .java file
The file is saved under the folder C:\Java

I browsed over to C:\Java folder and then compiled the file using the javac command, looks like it was successfully as the class file was created in the folder.

See images below:
[Compile command][1]

[The folder after the compile command run successfully][2]

Then on the same folder (C:\JAVA) I run the command:
    java FirstJavaProgram
(without .class)

[The error when trying to run java command][3]

I am adding also screenshots of the variables

This is all the information I have, if you need something else please let me know

```
 [1]: <https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot9bJ.png>
 [2]: <https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBa4S.png>
 [3]: <https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVpRj.png>
 [4]: <https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVLOk.png>
 [5]: <https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUbj5.png>
 [6]: <https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMEgp.png>
```

Comment: It wold be useful to post the exact command you used to compile and run the class.

Comment: on windows cmd type `java` and check either you are getting some response. If yes then, move to the directory where you have save __FirstJavaProgram.java__ and type `javac FirstJavaProgram.java` then `java FirstJavaProgram`

Comment: I just tried "javac FirstJavaProgram.java" followed by "java FirstJavaProgram" in a test folder with your code and it worked. I suspect you might have a path or classpath issue, but we will know more when you post the exact commands and errors.

Comment: Don't set the CLASSPATH. Only do that for more advanced exercises.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include the commands you executed in the command line and the output/errors you get from them. Also include the whole content of your `.java` file to your question or confirm that it is the whole content of the file.

Comment: Here you have some more information:
I saved the .java file under C:\Java folder
Then I compiled the code using the command javac FirstJavaProgram.java (Looks like it worked as the .class file was created)
Then I tried to run the code using the command java C:\JAVA\FirstJavaProgram
I got the error, and then I tried to run it again but this time I tried to run in from the folder that the class file is located on, same error

Comment: regarding the environment vars:
Path including: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin
CLASSPATH including: C:\Java

Comment: @AvidorHershkovitz You have to run `java FirstJavaProgram`, not `java C:\JAVA\FirstJavaProgram`. Your class is called `FirstJavaProgram`, not `C:\JAVA\FirstJavaProgram`. The argument for the `java` program must be a class name, not a path or a file.

Comment: I tried it also:
C:\Java>java FirstJavaProgram
Error: Could not find or load main class FirstJavaProgram
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FirstJavaProgram

Comment: I have updated the original ticket with all of the details, let me know if something else is missing

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of Java.
try "java FirstJavaProgram" on terminal window in the folder where you have class file, please make sure that at the end of file name there is no ".class"

Comment: Though you have copied the java code in your question, but want to clarify if your java file has any package statement. Probably at this point you should share the exact command and code you are using. It will be easy for anyone to help you instead of guesing. If you want you can add screen print that may also help us to solve your problem.

Comment: Since you are beginner, I want to add that after you saved the "FirstJavaProgram.java" file in afolder, from command terminal do compile it by using "javac FirstJavaProgram.java" once it is successfully compiled you will see a new file "FirstJavaProgram.class" once you have it try to run using command mentioned in my commend earlier. Hope this helps. As everyone suggested sharing more information will help in helping you.

Comment: I have updated the ticket original text with more details, can anyway try to solve my problem

Comment: From your "c:\java" folder can you try "java -cp . FirstJavaProgram"

Comment: It actually worked, Can you explain the reason behind it ?

Comment: With the option "-cd ." or "-classpath ." to java you are telling java where to look for class file in path, "." represents current folder and that is where you class file is. hope this explains you why it is working.

Answer (score 0):

From your "c:\java" folder can you try "java -cp . FirstJavaProgram"